# Enable Azure diagnostics logging using a CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-diagnostics, azure-cli

I am trying to achieve achieve [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log), however I would like to enable diagnostics logging using whatever form of non-human interaction possible. I would like to incorporate something that enables diagnostics logging during my build step, by default these are turned off it seems. Any Powsershell (using Azure RM) or visual studio team service build tasks available to make this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with [Azure CLI 2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli). You could use the following command.

```
az webapp log config --name
                     --resource-group
                     [--application-logging {false, true}]
                     [--detailed-error-messages {false, true}]
                     [--failed-request-tracing {false, true}]
                     [--level {error, information, verbose, warning}]
                     [--slot]
                     [--web-server-logging {filesystem, off, storage}]
```

Get help from az help command `az webapp log config -h` or the [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log#config).

```
#an example
az webapp log config --name shui -g shuiapp --application-logging true --web-server-logging filesystem
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a look through now :)